# GPRS and Weather Shields

Tags: arduino-uno, wire-library

I have GPRS(GPRS_Shield_V1.0), weather shield and arduino uno R3. When I use Arduino and GPRS it works perfectly and when I used Weather Shield it also worked perfectly. But weather shield needs wire library, to use sensors. And when I use GPRS library with wire library, my program prints the same string many times. How I can use these two shields together?

These are some pics of my connected shields:

http://puu.sh/gcvk3/85595c38c7.jpg

http://puu.sh/gcvpc/22185212d3.jpg

As you can see, I'm not using A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 pins for GPRS Shield. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked whether you are running out of memory?

Comment: Yes. My arduino are running out of memory. Thank you!